# Drag and drop with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I just tried a walkthrough for creating drag and drop-enabled features. I followed the guide at http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/index.html

Even though the guide is well written I cant get this to function, any obvious mistakes here? All of my code is pasted below and the guide authors comments are there as well to clarify. When I run the page displays all the items but nothing happens when I try moving them.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">


<script type="text/javascript">
    // iMouseDown represents the current mouse button state: up or down
    /*
    lMouseState represents the previous mouse button state so that we can
    check for button clicks and button releases:
    if(iMouseDown && !lMouseState) // button just clicked!
    if(!iMouseDown && lMouseState) // button just released!
    */
    var mouseOffset = null;
    var iMouseDown = false;
    var lMouseState = false;
    var dragObject = null;
    // Demo 0 variables
    var DragDrops = [];
    var curTarget = null;
    var lastTarget = null;
    var dragHelper = null;
    var tempDiv = null;
    var rootParent = null;
    var rootSibling = null;
    Number.prototype.NaN0 = function () { return isNaN(this) ? 0 : this; }
    function CreateDragContainer() {
        /*
        Create a new "Container Instance" so that items from one "Set" can not
        be dragged into items from another "Set"
        */
        var cDrag = DragDrops.length;
        DragDrops[cDrag] = [];
        /*
        Each item passed to this function should be a "container".  Store each
        of these items in our current container
        */
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var cObj = arguments[i];
            DragDrops[cDrag].push(cObj);
            cObj.setAttribute('DropObj', cDrag);
            /*
            Every top level item in these containers should be draggable.  Do this
            by setting the DragObj attribute on each item and then later checking
            this attribute in the mouseMove function
            */
            for (var j = 0; j < cObj.childNodes.length; j++) {
                // Firefox puts in lots of #text nodes...skip these
                if (cObj.childNodes[j].nodeName == '#text') continue;
                cObj.childNodes[j].setAttribute('DragObj', cDrag);
            }
        }

    }
    function mouseMove(ev) {
        ev = ev || window.event;
        /*
        We are setting target to whatever item the mouse is currently on
        Firefox uses event.target here, MSIE uses event.srcElement
        */
        var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
        var mousePos = mouseCoords(ev);
        // mouseOut event - fires if the item the mouse is on has changed
        if (lastTarget && (target !== lastTarget)) {
            // reset the classname for the target element
            var origClass = lastTarget.getAttribute('origClass');
            if (origClass) lastTarget.className = origClass;
        }
        /*
        dragObj is the grouping our item is in (set from the createDragContainer function).
        if the item is not in a grouping we ignore it since it can't be dragged with this
        script.
        */
        var dragObj = target.getAttribute('DragObj');
        // if the mouse was moved over an element that is draggable
        if (dragObj != null) {
            // mouseOver event - Change the item's class if necessary
            if (target != lastTarget) {
                var oClass = target.getAttribute('overClass');
                if (oClass) {
                    target.setAttribute('origClass', target.className);
                    target.className = oClass;
                }
            }
            // if the user is just starting to drag the element
            if (iMouseDown && !lMouseState) {

                // mouseDown target
                curTarget = target;
                // Record the mouse x and y offset for the element
                rootParent = curTarget.parentNode;
                rootSibling = curTarget.nextSibling;
                mouseOffset = getMouseOffset(target, ev);
                // We remove anything that is in our dragHelper DIV so we can put a new item in it.
                for (var i = 0; i < dragHelper.childNodes.length; i++) dragHelper.removeChild(dragHelper.childNodes[i]);
                // Make a copy of the current item and put it in our drag helper.
                dragHelper.appendChild(curTarget.cloneNode(true));
                dragHelper.style.display = 'block';
                // set the class on our helper DIV if necessary
                var dragClass = curTarget.getAttribute('dragClass');
                if (dragClass) {
                    dragHelper.firstChild.className = dragClass;
                }
                // disable dragging from our helper DIV (it's already being dragged)
                dragHelper.firstChild.removeAttribute('DragObj');
                /*
                Record the current position of all drag/drop targets related
                to the element.  We do this here so that we do not have to do
                it on the general mouse move event which fires when the mouse
                moves even 1 pixel.  If we don't do this here the script
                would run much slower.
                */
                var dragConts = DragDrops[dragObj];
                /*
                first record the width/height of our drag item.  Then hide it since
                it is going to (potentially) be moved out of its parent.
                */
                curTarget.setAttribute('startWidth', parseInt(curTarget.offsetWidth));
                curTarget.setAttribute('startHeight', parseInt(curTarget.offsetHeight));
                curTarget.style.display = 'none';
                // loop through each possible drop container
                for (var i = 0; i < dragConts.length; i++) {
                    with (dragConts[i]) {
                        var pos = getPosition(dragConts[i]);
                        /*
                        save the width, height and position of each container.
                        Even though we are saving the width and height of each
                        container back to the container this is much faster because
                        we are saving the number and do not have to run through
                        any calculations again.  Also, offsetHeight and offsetWidth
                        are both fairly slow.  You would never normally notice any
                        performance hit from these two functions but our code is
                        going to be running hundreds of times each second so every
                        little bit helps!
                        Note that the biggest performance gain here, by far, comes
                        from not having to run through the getPosition function
                        hundreds of times.
                        */
                        setAttribute('startWidth', parseInt(offsetWidth));
                        setAttribute('startHeight', parseInt(offsetHeight));
                        setAttribute('startLeft', pos.x);
                        setAttribute('startTop', pos.y);
                    }
                    // loop through each child element of each container
                    for (var j = 0; j < dragConts[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
                        with (dragConts[i].childNodes[j]) {
                            if ((nodeName == '#text') || (dragConts[i].childNodes[j] == curTarget)) continue;
                            var pos = getPosition(dragConts[i].childNodes[j]);
                            // save the width, height and position of each element
                            setAttribute('startWidth', parseInt(offsetWidth));
                            setAttribute('startHeight', parseInt(offsetHeight));
                            setAttribute('startLeft', pos.x);
                            setAttribute('startTop', pos.y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // If we get in here we are dragging something
        if (curTarget) {
            // move our helper div to wherever the mouse is (adjusted by mouseOffset)
            dragHelper.style.top = mousePos.y - mouseOffset.y;
            dragHelper.style.left = mousePos.x - mouseOffset.x;
            var dragConts = DragDrops[curTarget.getAttribute('DragObj')];
            var activeCont = null;
            var xPos = mousePos.x - mouseOffset.x + (parseInt(curTarget.getAttribute('startWidth')) / 2);
            var yPos = mousePos.y - mouseOffset.y + (parseInt(curTarget.getAttribute('startHeight')) / 2);
            // check each drop container to see if our target object is "inside" the container
            for (var i = 0; i < dragConts.length; i++) {
                with (dragConts[i]) {
                    if (((getAttribute('startLeft')) < xPos) &&
                    ((getAttribute('startTop')) < yPos) &&
                    ((getAttribute('startLeft') + getAttribute('startWidth')) > xPos) &&
                    ((getAttribute('startTop') + getAttribute('startHeight')) > yPos)) {
                        /*
                        our target is inside of our container so save the container into
                        the activeCont variable and then exit the loop since we no longer
                        need to check the rest of the containers
                        */
                        activeCont = dragConts[i];
                        // exit the for loop
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Our target object is in one of our containers.  Check to see where our div belongs
            if (activeCont) {
                // beforeNode will hold the first node AFTER where our div belongs
                var beforeNode = null;
                // loop through each child node (skipping text nodes).
                for (var i = activeCont.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    with (activeCont.childNodes[i]) {
                        if (nodeName == '#text') continue;
                        // if the current item is "After" the item being dragged
                        if (
                        curTarget != activeCont.childNodes[i] &&
                        ((getAttribute('startLeft') + getAttribute('startWidth')) > xPos) &&
                        ((getAttribute('startTop') + getAttribute('startHeight')) > yPos)) {
                            beforeNode = activeCont.childNodes[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                // the item being dragged belongs before another item
                if (beforeNode) {
                    if (beforeNode != curTarget.nextSibling) {
                        activeCont.insertBefore(curTarget, beforeNode);
                    }
                    // the item being dragged belongs at the end of the current container
                } else {
                    if ((curTarget.nextSibling) || (curTarget.parentNode != activeCont)) {
                        activeCont.appendChild(curTarget);
                    }
                }
                // make our drag item visible
                if (curTarget.style.display != '') {
                    curTarget.style.display = '';
                }
            } else {
                // our drag item is not in a container, so hide it.
                if (curTarget.style.display != 'none') {
                    curTarget.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
        // track the current mouse state so we can compare against it next time
        lMouseState = iMouseDown;
        // mouseMove target
        lastTarget = target;
        // track the current mouse state so we can compare against it next time
        lMouseState = iMouseDown;
        // this helps prevent items on the page from being highlighted while dragging
        return false;
    }
    function mouseUp(ev) {
        if (curTarget) {
            // hide our helper object - it is no longer needed
            dragHelper.style.display = 'none';
            // if the drag item is invisible put it back where it was before moving it
            if (curTarget.style.display == 'none') {
                if (rootSibling) {
                    rootParent.insertBefore(curTarget, rootSibling);
                } else {
                    rootParent.appendChild(curTarget);
                }
            }
            // make sure the drag item is visible
            curTarget.style.display = '';
        }
        curTarget = null;
        iMouseDown = false;
    }
    function mouseDown() {
        iMouseDown = true;
        if (lastTarget) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    document.onmousemove = mouseMove;  
    document.onmousedown = mouseDown;
    document.onmouseup = mouseUp;
    window.onload = function () {
        // Create our helper object that will show the item while dragging
        dragHelper = document.createElement('DIV');
        dragHelper.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;display:none;';
        CreateDragContainer(
        document.getElementById('DragContainer1'),
        document.getElementById('DragContainer2'),
        document.getElementById('DragContainer3')
    );
        document.body.appendChild(dragHelper);
    }

    function mouseCoords(ev) {
        if (ev.pageX || ev.pageY) {
            return { x: ev.pageX, y: ev.pageY };
        }
        return {
            x: ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
            y: ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop - document.body.clientTop
        };
    }


</script>
    <title>Drag and drop test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!--the mouse over and dragging class are defined on each item-->
<div class="DragContainer" id="DragContainer1">
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item1"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #1</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item2"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #2</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item3"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #3</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item4"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #4</div>
</div>
<div class="DragContainer" id="DragContainer2">
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item5"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #5</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item6"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #6</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item7"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #7</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item8"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #8</div>
</div>
<div class="DragContainer" id="DragContainer3">
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item9"  overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #9</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item10" overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #10</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item11" overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #11</div>
    <div class="DragBox" id="Item12" overClass="OverDragBox" dragClass="DragDragBox">Item #12</div>
</div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the javascript console say? Any errors, that should be the first place to look to help you debug.

Comment: Thanks I am trying this using jQuery UI right now, seems to be extremely time-saving. Kind of awesome that jQuery is for free.

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss some javascript references? Chrome is screaming that it does not find a function getMouseOffset (line 95)